# How to allow part of a transaction to fail in Spring/Hibernate webapp?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a situation in my webapp for which I haven't been able to find a good solution yet. In my app, a user can do a search against an external (to my app) music database. I conduct the search on their behalf and then present the results.

Then they can choose to add one or more of those results to their user record. Internally, I create a row in a table for the song (if it's not already in my DB), copy the song information, and then add it to their collection.

The problem is that two users could both attempt to add the same song to the DB (which has a uniqueness constraint). One user would succeed, and the other would fail, but not until the end of the overall transaction. If user A wins and user B does not, I don't want the addition of the song to the DB to fail; I want to catch that error, load the (now present) song from my DB, and continue with the request to add it to the user’s collection.

From what I read in the Hibernate docs (here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow), this is not how it's intended to be used. Sure, I can let the overall transaction fail, and report this to the user, but it's a bad user experience for a situation that should be recoverable.

Is there a non-hacky way to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about concurrency or about DB constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Can you synchronize those transactions?  Look into concurrency as I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, u can use the concept of monitor and semaphore in it. As consider saving as a critical area and pass the both thread through mutex so access will be provided to only one other will have to wait.
once one done other can enter the critical area.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways, either prevent the error by raising the isolation level of the business method to `SERIALIZABLE`, check if the song exists first and only then insert it.

No other isolation level would suffice as in this case we need protection against phantom reads.

Otherwise optimistic locking can be used. Spring will translate the Hibernate exception into a spring `OptimisticLockingFailureException`.

This can be caught in the method that calls the business method:

```
@Service
public class SongService {
    @Transactional
    public void addSongIfNotExists() {
        ...
    }
}


@Service
public class AddSongFailureHandlingService {

    @Autowired
    private SongService songService;

    // NEVER makes sure no transaction is ongoing, that would prevent commit after 
    // calling addSongIfNotExists
    @Transactional(propagation= Propagation.NEVER)
    public callingMethod() {

        try {
            // no transaction is propagated to this method, this will cause a
            // commit attempt
            songService.addSongIfNotExists();

        } catch(OptimisticLockingFailureException exc) {
            // transaction rolled back, song already inserted
            // apply recovery logic
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

It's important to know that after a transaction rollback, any entity manager / hibernate session opened needs to be discarded.

So if you need to do something in the database to recover from the optimistic locking exception, make sure to call another `@Transactional` business method so that you get a fresh session / entity manager.